# How to set Marks in a method?

Tags: java, set

So this is my first day trying to learn how to do a bit of coding. My overall program is to be able to get user data which contains their results for 2 subjects with 3 assignments in each.

Below is the first part of my code:

```
public class AssignmentMarks {

   private String courseName; // Field variables
   private int assignment1;
   private int assignment2;
   private int assignment3;
   int average;
   int mark;

   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

   public AssignmentMarks(String name, int mark1, int mark2, int mark3)
   {
       this.courseName = name;
       this.assignment1 = mark1;
       this.assignment2 = mark2;
       this.assignment3 = mark3;

       AssignmentMarks instance = new AssignmentMarks(name, mark2, mark3, mark1);
   }

   public void setMark(int assignmentNumber, int mark)
   {

       // used to set the value of the assignments
       // assignmentNumber represents the number of the assignment to set (ass1, ass2, ass3)
       // mark is the score of the assignment (0 to 100)
   } 
}
```

The code `public void setMark(int assignmentNumber, int mark)` is what im struggling to figure out if anyone can please give me some guidance that would be amazing and very helpful.

Comment: You need to go through your concepts again, there are LOT of things wrong in this code. Go through your concepts where are you using `scanner`. there will be a `stackoverflowException` in your constructor. `assignmentNumber` is an `int` you are saying it will contain 3 marks ....

Comment: You have a number of problems in this class and should really do a refresher on how to make objects in java. The way you designed the class, the only real way to do this would be to use an if-else chain, or switch statement, with a condition for each assignment. i.e `if (assignmentNumber == 1) {assignment1 = mark;}`. I implore you to learn about arrays, as this would make your implementation far more extensible.

Comment: I would change the methods and constructors but they have been set up like this on purpose and cant change it. If I do the if statement for the assignment number how would I do the mark does anyone know?

Comment: Hint.  You have declared 3 variables for the assignment marks.  So use `if` statements to decide which of the variables to assign to.